# Python file zipping and unzipping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `pyminizip` to zip and password protect a file. Everyting is working fine but I am not able to understand the unzipping of files. I read the library's README but it is confusing and the unzipping is not helping me. Here is my code.

**Zipping**

```
pyminizip.compress("src_file", None, "dest.zip", "password", 5)
```

**Unzipping**

```
pyminizip.uncompress("file.zip", "password", "dest_path", int(withoutpath))
```

**ERROR**

```
SystemError: <built-in function uncompress> returned a result with an error set
```

What I dont know is what is the fourth argument, `int(withoutpath)` in the `uncompress()`.

The official docs say

```
pyminizip.compress("/srcfile/path.txt", "file_path_prefix", "/distfile/path.zip", "password", int(compress_level))

Args:
1. src file path (string)
2. src file prefix path (string) or None (path to prepend to file)
3. dst file path (string)
4. password (string) or None (to create no-password zip)
5. compress_level(int) between 1 to 9, 1 (more fast) <---> 9 (more compress) or 0 (default)

Return value:
- always returns None

pyminizip.compress_multiple([u'pyminizip.so', 'file2.txt'], [u'/path_for_file1', u'/path_for_file2'], "file.zip", "1233", 4, progress)
Args:
1. src file LIST path (list)
2. src file LIST prefix path (list) or []
3. dst file path (string)
4. password (string) or None (to create no-password zip)
5. compress_level(int) between 1 to 9, 1 (more fast) <---> 9 (more compress)
6. optional function to be called during processing which takes one argument, the count of how many files have been compressed

Return value:
- always returns None

pyminizip.uncompress("/srcfile/path.zip", "password", "/dirtoextract", int(withoutpath))
1. src file path (string)
2. password (string) or None (to unzip encrypted archives)
3. dir path to extract files or None (to extract in a specific dir or cwd)
4. withoutpath (exclude path of extracted)

Return value:
- always returns None
```

Kindly help me out. The fourth argument is really bugging me out and I am not able to find help anywhere else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyminizip
pyminizip.compress("src_file", None, "dest.zip", "password", 5)
pyminizip.uncompress("file.zip", "password", "dest_path", 0)
```

// code https://github.com/smihica/pyminizip/blob/master/src/py_miniunz.c#L227

```
   if ((*popt_extract_without_path)==0)
        write_filename = filename_inzip;
    else
        write_filename = filename_withoutpath;
```

Comment: It does not work. Tried it already. Throws the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: are u using windows?

Comment: yes i am using windows, and the link isn’t helpful.